# GWT, RoRails or Grails for a "Social Network"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, gwt, grails

Am thinking about building a social networking site,that can function more like an application then a site,thus giving it better performance and user interface.
what am stuck up with here is which would be the best framework to try this out?

GWT-i have some experience(about 2 years) with Java and it looks easy but the forum appears dead.

Ruby on Rails- i visited the website today,went through a few tutorials and it looks easy to learn,but i never programmed on this 1 before.

Grails - i have heard that this is a very god framework and based on java,but i've never personally tried it.

What would you think would be the right choice?
it would be cool if you consider factors like performance,scalability and the widgets already available.I don't really care about the development time...i've got more than 2months!

Comment: "Am thinking about building a social networking site" - I blame that film...

Comment: me to,but this is something different then facebook or twitter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially with a Java background, Grails would be a good choice. Grails is built on top of Spring and Hibernate, but makes using them much easier. No painful editing of XML config files.

Although, I'd make sure you evaluate using Ning and the existing open source projects before you bother building another one from scratch.

Comment: are we allowed to use GWT plugins in Grails?is Rails faster than Ruby on Rails on performance?is hosting Grails cheaper and easier then Ruby on Rails?

Comment: This is a GWT *for* Grails (http://www.grails.org/plugin/gwt). I've never used it. Nor have I ever used GWT, but I'd guess there are GWT plugins like there are jquery plugins? I'd think you'd be able to use them in Grails, but you'll have to give it a shot. I don't have any Rails experience, so I can't really speak to your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "more like an application then a site". If what you mean is give the app a desktop application feel, then I think GWT fits more. Though if you want to have something really fast, (half the development time that you'd use to develop it in GWT), then I'd recommend rails. I haven't tried Grails before but it seems neat.

Comment: @kibygen Not the desktop like feel,but the desktop like speed!,i dont realy consider of the development time.

Answer (score 0):

The best for you to use is ruby on rails if it about performance,scalability and the widgets
then you have no problem at all. It also has lots of gems/plugins that can help you so much

Comment: GWT is faster than rails by any chance?  and by the way,do i have an option like when the user enters the start/login page the website starts loading the layout of the profile(when the user is entering his id and password,this would make the initial startup faster.)?

Answer (score 0):

Read this book [Grails in action](http://www.manning.com/gsmith/).

It shows you how to make a social networking site using grails.

It uses an old version of Grails but you can adapt it.